# searchID cannot be used as function error

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I just learned some basic array topics and I would like to ask why my function *searchID* cannot be used as function. I've already checked the number of parameters for the prototype, calling function and the function header. can you point out my mistakes?

```css
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void getScore(int[],int,long[],int&);
void searchID(long[],int,bool&,int[]);
int main()
{
 int SIZE;
 long ID[SIZE],winnerID,searchID;
 int score1st[SIZE],score2nd[SIZE],totalScore[SIZE], avg1st, avg2nd,count;
 
 cout<<"Enter the number of players: ";
 cin>>SIZE;
 
 for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter bowler "<<i+1<<"'s ID: ";
  cin>>ID[i];
 }
 cout<<"\nFIRST ROUND SCORES: \n";
 getScore(score1st,SIZE,ID,avg1st);
 cout<<"\nSECOND ROUND SCORES: \n";
 getScore(score2nd,SIZE,ID,avg2nd);
 cout<<"\nThe player(s) who improve the scores in the second round:\n";
 for(int k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
 {
  if(score2nd[k]>score1st[k])
  {
   cout<<"Player "<<k+1<<", ID "<<ID[k]<<endl;
  }
 }
 cout<<"\nThe average score for the first round: "<<avg1st;
 cout<<"\nThe average score for the second round: "<<avg2nd;
 int highScore=totalScore[0];
 for(int m=0;m<SIZE;m++)
 {
  totalScore[m]=score1st[m]+score2nd[m];
  if(totalScore[m]>highScore)
  {
   highScore=totalScore[m];
   winnerID=ID[m];
   count=m+1;
  }
 }
 cout<<"\nThe WINNER is: Player"<<count<<", ID "<<winnerID<<" with the HIGHEST score "<<highScore<<endl<<endl;
 bool idFound=false;
 searchID(ID,SIZE,idFound,totalScore);
 while(!idFound)
 {
  cout<<"The data is not available!\n\n";
  searchID(SIZE,ID,idFound,totalScore);
 }
 
 return 0;
}
void getScore(int score[], int size,long id[], int& avg)
{
 int total=0;
 for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter the total score for player "<<j+1<<", ID "<<id[j]<<": ";
  cin>>score[j];
  total=total+score[j];
 }
 avg=total/size;
}
void searchID(long id[],int size,bool& foundID,int total[])
{
 long searchPlayer;
 cout<<"Enter the ID of the player you want to search: ";
 cin>>searchPlayer;
 for(int n=0;n<size;n++)
 {
  if(searchPlayer==id[n])
  {
   foundID=true;
   cout<<"The total score of player "<<n+1<<" with ID "<<id[n]<<" is: "<<total[n]<<endl<<endl;
  }
 }
 
}
```

the ID and the total score are both arrays. For the first function which is *getScore* function it turns out to be completely fine but there's error when i include the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redeclaration of `searchID`.

first as a function, outside `main()`, and the other as a local variable in `main()`.

```
void searchID(long[],int,bool&,int[]); // function declaration
long ..., searchID;                    // local variable declaration in main()
```

As per [basic.scope#block-1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope#block-1)

> A name declared in a block is **local** to that block; it has block scope.
>   Its potential scope **begins** at its point of declaration and ends at the
>   end of its block. A variable declared at block scope is a *local
>   variable*.

Thus, the nearest possible declaration of `searchID` in `main()` is apparently the local variable declaration. Thus the error.

Comment: and now i have a lot more things to fix XD

Comment: but it's fine now. thank you so much for your help. really appreciate it

Comment: @SabariahHashim, if this answer has helped you, feel free to mark this as the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fixed!

```css
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void getScore(int[],int,long[],int&);
void searchID(long[],int,bool&,int[]);
int main()
{
 int SIZE;
 long ID[SIZE],winnerID;
 int score1st[SIZE],score2nd[SIZE],totalScore[SIZE], avg1st, avg2nd,count;
 
 cout<<"Enter the number of players: ";
 cin>>SIZE;
 
 for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter bowler "<<i+1<<"'s ID: ";
  cin>>ID[i];
 }
 cout<<"\nFIRST ROUND SCORES: \n";
 getScore(score1st,SIZE,ID,avg1st);
 cout<<"\nSECOND ROUND SCORES: \n";
 getScore(score2nd,SIZE,ID,avg2nd);
 cout<<"\nThe player(s) who improve the scores in the second round:\n";
 for(int k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
 {
  if(score2nd[k]>score1st[k])
  {
   cout<<"Player "<<k+1<<", ID "<<ID[k]<<endl;
  }
 }
 cout<<"\nThe average score for the first round: "<<avg1st;
 cout<<"\nThe average score for the second round: "<<avg2nd;
 int highScore=totalScore[0];
 for(int m=0;m<SIZE;m++)
 {
  totalScore[m]=score1st[m]+score2nd[m];
  if(totalScore[m]>highScore)
  {
   highScore=totalScore[m];
   winnerID=ID[m];
   count=m+1;
  }
 }
 cout<<"\nThe WINNER is: Player"<<count<<", ID "<<winnerID<<" with the HIGHEST score "<<highScore<<endl<<endl;
 bool idFound=false;
 searchID(ID,SIZE,idFound,totalScore);
 while(!idFound)
 {
  cout<<"The data is not available!\n\n";
  searchID(ID,SIZE,idFound,totalScore);
 }
 
 return 0;
}
void getScore(int score[], int size,long id[], int& avg)
{
 int total=0;
 for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter the total score for player "<<j+1<<", ID "<<id[j]<<": ";
  cin>>score[j];
  total=total+score[j];
 }
 avg=total/size;
}
void searchID(long id[],int size,bool& foundID,int total[])
{
 long searchPlayer;
 cout<<"Enter the ID of the player you want to search: ";
 cin>>searchPlayer;
 for(int n=0;n<size;n++)
 {
  if(searchPlayer==id[n])
  {
   foundID=true;
   cout<<"The total score of player "<<n+1<<" with ID "<<id[n]<<" is: "<<total[n]<<endl<<endl;
  }
 }
 
}
```